# How can I enable customized action with CanCan?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cancan

I have actions called 'follow' and 'unfollow' in my controller.
Obviously, CanCan won't recognize those actions so that it shows access denied when those actions are executed.

```
alias_action :follow, :unfollow :to => :read
```

I added this line to **ability.rb** then it works fine now.
But the problem is when the user is not logged in it shows error like this

```
syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
    alias_action :follow, :unfollow :to => :read
```

I only enable those actions when user is logged in.
How can I? What should I add to **ability.rb**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you're missing a comma:

```
alias_action :follow, :unfollow, :to => :read
```

see [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Action-Aliases)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your controller to be UsersController, you can do this in your ability.rb fie

```
def initialize(user)
  user || = User.new
  if user.roles.include?('tweeple')    #Assuming the user with role tweeple can follow/ unfollow
    can [:follow, :unfollow], User
  end
end
```